# gridview crash in real android device but working fine in android emulator

Tags: android

I have an fragment for showing images in gridview, it's open at click of naviagation drawer item , it is working fine with android emualtor but it crash on real android device

here is my frament_info_photos

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.abcd.InfoPhotos">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:text="photos" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@color/Shade_browm"/>
    <GridView
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/photos_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"></GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

InfoPhotos.java

```
public class InfoPhotos extends Fragment {
    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_photos, container, false);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.photos_fragment);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {


            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

and my ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int images[] ={R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5,
            R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7, R.drawable.img8, R.drawable.img9};
    Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if(arg1 == null)
        {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(90, 90));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            imageView = (ImageView) arg1;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(images[arg0]);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

i don't know what's wrong with code

Comment: Please post crashlog

Comment: it is crashed on real device so i don't have crash report, it is working fine with android emulator

Comment: connect device with USB and read logcat error, what is the version of your device?

Comment: check for permission if the device is marshmallow

Comment: @ZakiPathan which permission required to check here?

Comment: @user2025187 from where images comes in grid?

Comment: @ZakiPathan Check images[] in ImageAdapter. drawable images not required any permission

Comment: connect device with USB and read logcat error and post logcat here

Comment: what kind of permission, my testing device is lenovo k4 note and it is currently running on marsmallow

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply,

Comment: here is my log :  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 4188752 free bytes and 69MB until OOM
                                                             at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)